# Cannot start Eclipse Juno after update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have ran an update to my installed features in Eclipse.  Now Eclipse won't start.  I have removed the .lock file.  I have no .snap file.  I have already re-installed and unzipped eclipse to replace my current eclipse directory.  Here is the .log file after I run eclipse with -clean:

> !SESSION 2012-11-07 10:11:05.302
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800 java.version=1.7.0_02
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.mobile.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.mobile.product -clean
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 2 0 2012-11-07 10:11:11.117 !MESSAGE
>   [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details:  Component1 :
>   Component[    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event    activate = activate
>     deactivate = deactivate     modified =      configuration-policy = optional
>     factory = null  autoenable = true   immediate = false   implementation
>   = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent   state = Unsatisfied     properties =    serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
>   [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]   references = null   located in
>   bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.100.v20110502 [329] ]
>   Component2: Component[    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event    activate =
>   activate  deactivate = deactivate     modified =      configuration-policy =
>   optional  factory = null  autoenable = true   immediate = false
>     implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
>     state = Unsatisfied     properties =    serviceFactory = false
>     serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]  references =
>   null  located in bundle =
>   org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049 [328] ]
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2012-11-07
>   10:11:11.151 !MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names!
>   Details:  Component1 : Component[     name =
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf  activate = activate     deactivate
>   = deactivate  modified =      configuration-policy = optional     factory = null  autoenable = true   immediate = false   implementation =
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
>     state = Unsatisfied     properties =
>   {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
>     serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
>   [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]    references =
>   null  located in bundle =
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.0.v20111128-0624 [367] ]
>   Component2: Component[    name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
>     activate = activate     deactivate = deactivate     modified = 
>     configuration-policy = optional     factory = null  autoenable = true
>     immediate = false   implementation =
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
>     state = Unsatisfied     properties =
>   {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
>     serviceFactory = false  serviceInterface =
>   [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]    references =
>   null  located in bundle =
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.v20120305-0333 [366] ]
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-11-07 10:11:26.746
>   !MESSAGE Unable to create class
>   'org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon' from bundle '268'
>   !STACK 0 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager to
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager to
>   org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager  at
>   java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:566)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon.init(CommandServiceAddon.java:30)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>     ... 27 more

Has anybody seen this error and knows how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Unzip Eclipse Juno into a different directory and never ever try to update Eclipse again.

Comment: If you're doing Android development, then you will want to update your SDK once in a while.  And when you do, you will also have to update ADT plugin in Eclipse.  No getting around this.

Comment: Sure there is.  Create a new development environment in a different directory by unzipping the latest Eclipse and adding your ADT plug-in.  Zip up your ADT Eclipse in case it gets corrupted.  Copy your workspace to a different directory so you have a fall back environment if your new environment develops a problem.  Never update a working Eclipse development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  But what about all my other plugins like Check Style, FindBugs, etc.

Comment: Add them to your new Eclipse development environment one plug-in at a time.  Check to make sure you can start Eclipse after each plug-in.  After you've installed all of the additional plug-ins, you zip up your ADT Eclipse so you don't have to go through this exercise again until you're ready to build a newer Eclipse development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved it by downloading and unzipping Eclipse into a different directory, and copying my old plugins + bundles folders into it.